# Creating a Sharepoint Workflow task in a specific task list?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow

I'm developing a sequential Sharepoint Foundation (Share point 2010) workflow in Visual Studio.

I can create tasks no problem using a CreateTask activity, but I can't work out how to create the task on a specific task list (i.e. a task list other than the one associated with the workflow).

How can I specify the task list on which the task should be created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't with the buildin taks activities. The whole point with all the ...Task activities is that they work with the Task list assigned during association.

If you need to add tasks to another task list then you do that as you would add items to any other list, but that means that you'll have no way of using any of the OnTask... functionality

Comment: Thanks.  I am going to stick with the single task list assigned to the workflow.  Although separate task lists seemed like a good idea for what I was trying to achieve, the constant barrage of obstacles and increasingly complex workarounds makes the separate task lists unfeasible.